# static variable re-initializes

Tags: c++, static-members

Could someone help me understand, why the variable masterID, defined static, in the following class re-initializes, if a new instance with a non-default constructor is created?

```
static unsigned int masterID=0;

class game{
public:
   unsigned int m_id;
   unsigned int m_players;

   // default constructor
   game():m_id(masterID++){

   }

   // another constructor using a game instance
   game(game g): m_id(masterID++){
   ...
   }

   // copy constructor
   // copy constructor
   game(const game &o)
   : m_id(o.m_id), m_players(o.m_players)
   {    }

   // assignment operator
   game& operator =(const game o){
    m_id = o.m_id;
    m_players = o.m_players;
    return *this;
};
```

with this code, as long as I create instances using the default constructor, such as

```
game g1, g2;
```

the m_id takes on values as 0, 1, 2,... etc.

But, if now I create a third instance as

```
game g3(g2);
```

the m_id for g3 is again 0.

I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: The `static unsigned int masterID=0;` line is **not** in your `.h` file, is it?

Comment: [Works just fine](http://ideone.com/Mhy6l) as you've shown it, so obviously the problem is in code you haven't shown. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Are you telling us all the facts? I tried your code, the second constructor does not reset masterID. But I needed to fix the myID identifier, so this is not the true code.

Comment: is myID and m_id a typo and should be the same?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `static unsigned int masterID=0;` is in my `.h` file.

Comment: @Nikhil : If so, that's your problem -- each translation unit gets a separate variable when a variable is declared static in a header.

Comment: @ildjam: you are right. The code now works well. But the problem reappears when one new instance is created, using two previous instances... more like using a constructor 'game(game g1, game g2)`

Comment: @Nikhil : You'll need to provide a custom copy constructor instead of relying on the default, compiler-generated one.

Comment: @idljam: I do have a copy constructor (as well as assignment operator overloaded). But, it doesn't seem to work. The problem persist, if one game instance (say) g1 generates a `new` game instance say g3 :(

Comment: @Nikhil : `game(game g)` is not a copy constructor. If you have a real copy constructor then it would be helpful if you actually showed it in your question.

Comment: @idljam: added a copy constructor... in particular, I tried forcing m_id to be some specific value using the copy constructor, but `game g3(g2)` doesn't seem to be using anything from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `static unsigned int masterID=0;` is in your `.h` file. It should not be there: the way you have it now, you get a *separate* static variable *in each compilation unit* that includes your `.h` file.

The right way of doing it is to declare `masterID` static *in your class*, and initialize it in a single `.cpp` file.

In your .h file:

```
class game{
public:
    unsigned int m_id;
    unsigned int m_players;
    static unsigned int masterID; // no initialization!

   // default constructor
   game():m_id(masterID++){

   }

   // another constructor
   game(unsigned int players): m_id(masterID++), m_players(players){

   }
};
```

In your cpp file:

```
game::masterID = 0;
```

Comment: the problem still exists in a new instance, created using a previous one, with `game gNew(gExisting)`

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi Your constructor `game(game g): m_id(masterID++)` is highly suspicious. It shouldn't be there. If the effect that you want is for the copy to get a new ID, you should set it in your copy constructor. I assume that you removed the free-standing `static unsigned int masterID=0;` line from your .h file, right?